# How to display Swashbuckle parameter object only with fields that should actually be sent?

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I'm starting to work with [Swagger](https://swagger.io/) using the [Swashbuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore) library for AspNetCore.

And when putting in my API an object with references it presents as if it were necessary to send all the fields of the references, when only the identifier (Id)

## Here's an example:

#### Model Structure:

```cs
public class Cidade
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public Uf Uf { get; set; }
}

public class Uf
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public Pais Pais { get; set; }
}

public class Pais
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

#### And the following API:

```cs
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/Cidade")]
public class CidadeController : Controller
{        
    // POST: api/Cidade
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody]Cidade value)
    {
    }
}
```

The result in Swagger is as follows:

[image]

And what I would like is the following (only up to `uf.id`):

[image]

## How can I get this result?

Comment: I think you can provide your own custom example... can you share your swagger.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking on my samples and I think I found something you can use:
http://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index?filter=P#/PolygonVolume/PolygonVolume_Post

On my case I'm adding more, you need less, but still what you need is just a custom example...

[image]

the JSON looks like this:

```
"PolygonVolumeInsideParameter": {
  "properties": {
    "Points": {
      "items": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/Location"
      },
      "xml": {
        "name": "Location",
        "wrapped": true
      },
      "example": [
        {
          "Lat": 1.0,
          "Lon": 2.0
        },
        {
          "Lat": 5.0,
          "Lon": 6.0
        }
      ],
      "type": "array"
    },
    "PlanId": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "xml": {
    "name": "PolygonVolumeInsideParameter"
  },
  "type": "object"
},
```

And on swashbuckle I added the example it with an `ISchemaFilter` my code is here:
https://github.com/heldersepu/Swagger-Net-Test/blob/master/Swagger_Test/App_Start/SwaggerConfig.cs#L891

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was able to work out an initial solution to my problem!

Answer (score 2):

I followed the logic of [@HelderSepu answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51750953/2290538), to get my solution, which would be as follows:

I built a Schema filter to add an example to the reference properties (`Ref`), which has a property called "Id":

```cs
public class ApplySchemaRefIdExtensions : ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(Schema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {
        if (schema.Properties != null)
        {
            foreach (var p in schema.Properties)
            {
                if (p.Value.Example == null && p.Value.Ref != null)
                {
                    var reference = context.SystemType.GetProperty(p.Value.Ref.Split("/").LastOrDefault());
                    if (reference != null)
                    {
                        var id = reference.PropertyType.GetProperty("Id");
                        if (id != null)
                        {
                            p.Value.Example = new
                            {
                                Id = 123
                            };
                            p.Value.Ref = null;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On `Startup.cs`:

```cs
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    // ...
    c.SchemaFilter<ApplySchemaRefIdExtensions>();
});
```

---

#### Result for the same [example of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51747530/2290538):

[image]